# Testing Ninject (or any IoC container) bindings?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ninject

I am using Ninject in my ASP.NET MVC 3 project and now have a complicated object graph.

I would like some unit tests to ensure that all my required types are bindable - at the moment the only way I'm finding out is via the ASPX error page.

I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to do this.

Is it as simple as writing

```
_kernel.Get<IService>();
```

and letting the exception fail the test? Or is there a cleverer way to do this using the MVC hooks for DI?

Comment: Simple Injector DI container has a `Verify()` method that checks whether all registered objects can be resolved. By calling after the configuration phase it allows you to fail-fast. I run the complete configuration in a unit test as well to fail even faster. I don't know what features other DI containers have to allow this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additionally to ordinary unit tests, we have integration tests that test everything but UI and DB including the Ninject bindings. Therefore we setup everything as in production and rebind these parts to mocks. This will also test the Ninject bindings.

In case of MVC this means you have to create a kernel, load the same modules as in production and rebind the DB access. Then create an instance of the controller and call the actions you want to test and check if they behave as expected.